# Trying to visit URL without www. causes WordPress to try and load the non-existent /defaultsite page

Tags: wordpress

If I try to navigate to http://vequityintelligence.co.uk then WordPress redirects the browser (301 Moved Permanently) to http://www.vequityintelligence.co.uk/defaultsite which doesn't exist, so I get a 404 Not Found error.

- The htaccess file is the one that came with WordPress.
- I've refreshed my permalinks by changing the permalink format.
- The site frontpage is set to the 'Recent Posts' option, but changing this doesn't affect it.

I understand why I get redirected, but I don't understand where the addition of '/defaultsite' comes from.

I have searched google and SO with very few results, let alone any answers. I can't think what else might cause this.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you don't need this answer anymore, but adding it for posterity: weird as it sounds, I think it's a caching issue.

I just came across this with a client's site I'm working on, and was at my wit's end, but then found some references that said it worked okay in one browser but not another, and clearing the cache fixed it.

An easy test: if you visit the URL in a browser you've never used to visit it, do you still have the issue? If not, it's probably just a matter of clearing the cache in the browser that is giving you trouble.

Comment: agreed: clear the cache if you do anything which moves the site (Settings/Wordpress Address/Site Address).

Answer (score 1):

In the Wordpress dashboard > General Settings, check your setting for the Wordpress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL).

This is where I made sure the ‘www.’ was unnecessary for my URL.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but no joy. They both just show the domain name with the www, which is how I want it, I'd just prefer the homepage not to break when someone omits it.

Comment: Hmmm, it does. I gave up on fixing it, but the site uses a different theme now so that must be it. I just assumed (reasonably I hope) that handling requests and parsing URLs would be done by the WordPress core and that the theme was just a presentation layer that sits on top.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a problem with the htaccess file. Perhaps adding the following code to htaccess will resolve the problem.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This redirects non-www to www. Put this near the top so it is processed before other rules are.

Code found [here](http://dense13.com/blog/2008/02/27/redirecting-non-www-to-www-with-htaccess/)

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried this and still no success. The rule just isn't being processed even though it is at the top of the .htaccess file, so maybe that is something for me to look into. The redirect already works for other pages such as /news, but not for the site root.